# Programa me quita las primeras 3 letras del string

Tags: c++

estoy teniendo un problema con mi programa, ingreso un string pero al imprimirlo y ver que hay dentro me quita siempre las 3 primeras letras
Me ayudarían mucho enserio

```
int main(){
    int pc, pt, rb, num;
    string reg, reg2, reg3;
    
    vector<int> valores;
    vector<int> valorC;
    
    vector<string> registro;
    vector<string> registro2;
    vector<string> registro3;
    
    cin>>pc; cin>>pt; cin>>rb; 
    
    for(int i = 0; i<rb; i++){
        cout<<endl;
        cin>>num;
        cin.ignore(0);
        getline(cin, reg); cin.ignore('\n'); cin.ignore(0);
        getline(cin, reg2);
        
        
        registro.push_back(reg);
        registro2.push_back(reg2);
        valores.push_back(num);
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<registro2.size();i++){
        cout<<registro2[i]<<" ";
    }
    

    
    return 0;
}
```

El chiste es que ya tengo el programa, por eso todo lo comentado, solo que me fallan los strings, es todo y termino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diria que tu problema consiste simplemente en que haces varias llamadas a cin.ignore().

```
int main(){
    int pc, pt, rb, num;
    string reg, reg2, reg3;
    
    vector<int> valores;
    vector<int> valorC;
    
    vector<string> registro;
    vector<string> registro2;
    vector<string> registro3;
    
    cin>>pc; cin>>pt; cin>>rb; 
    
    for(int i = 0; i<rb; i++){
        cout<<endl;
        cin>>num;
        getline(cin, reg);
        getline(cin, reg2);
        
        
        registro.push_back(reg);
        registro2.push_back(reg2);
        valores.push_back(num);
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<registro2.size();i++){
        cout<<registro2[i]<<" ";
    }



return 0;
```

}

Comment: Luego de los `cin>>` se va a saltar el primer `getline` porque el buffer queda sucio.

Comment: Como podría limpiarlo? sin el cin.ignore me salta como mencionas, ya no se me ocurre como evitar esos saltos  Edit: Ya me salio, utilice fflush, anteriormente no me funcionaba pero al parecer ya me funciona